# Use of IF statement with matrices in fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran

I want to go through a matrix and check if any block of it is the same as a predefined unit. Here is my code. 'sd5' is the 2 by 2 predefined unit.

```
ALLOCATE (fList((n-1)**2,3))
fList = 0
p = 1
DO i = 1, n-1, 1
  DO j = 1, n-1, 1
    IF (TEST(i:i+1, j:j+1) == sd5) THEN
      fList(p,1:3) = (i, j+1, 101) ! 101 should be replaced by submatrix number
  END IF
  p = p+1
  END DO
END DO
```

The problem seems to be in the `IF` statement as four logical statements are returned in `TEST(i:i+1, j:j+1) == sd5`. I get this error:

```
Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression
```

I get another error:

```
fList(p,1:3) = (i, j+1, 101) ! 101 should be replaced by sub matrix number
     1
Error: Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant at (1)
```

I do not understand this error, as all variables are integer which I defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if statements require *scalar* clauses.

```
(TEST(i:i+1, j:j+1) == sd5)
```

results in a 2x2 *matrix* containing `.true.` or `.false.`. Since you want to check *all* entries, the statement should read

```
IF ( all( TEST(i:i+1, j:j+1) == sd5) ) THEN
```

[ You could also use `any` if only one matching entry is sufficient. ]

The second statement is a little tricky, since you do not state what you want to achieve. As it is, it is not what you would expect. My guess is that you are trying to store a vector of length three, and the assignment should read

```
fList(p,1:3) = (/ i, j+1, 101 /)
```

or

```
fList(p,1:3) = [ i, j+1, 101 ]
```

---

The syntax you provided is in fact used to specify complex constants:

```
( Real, Imag )
```

In this form, `Real` and `Imag` need to be constants or literals themselves, cf. the Fortran 2008 Standard, R417.

Comment: Wonderful, it compiles now! Thank you Alexander Vogt!